# Kerbal Space Program Unmanned modules

Tags: kerbal-space-program

How can I fly an unmanned module?

It shows `SPU:no connection` when I right click on it.

I have tried adding batteries, `comms dts m1` on it but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to have some command module to control unmanned vessel, i.e: [Stayputnik Mk. 1](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Stayputnik_Mk._1) which is opened with Basic Science tech, if you are playing carrer mode.

Comment: I was using stayputnik mk 1 but it does not launch when I press space and when I right click on it, it show "spu no connection".

Comment: Oh, it seems you are using "RemoteTech" mod, in this case you should refer to their docs, what I found here http://remotetechnologiesgroup.github.io/RemoteTech/ is: "You need to use an antenna that won’t break in the atmosphere to be able to control an unmanned rocket during atmospheric flight. The Reflectron DP-10, unlocked along with the Stayputnik probe core, is the earliest such antenna available."

Comment: I cant seem to find this. It is listed under which category?

Comment: It says it should be under "Science Parts" after researching Flight Control. More details here http://remotetechnologiesgroup.github.io/RemoteTech/guide/parts/

Comment: I found out what to do.
while constructing communotron 16 I had to check start extended.

Comment: @SubhasishBasak Please mark the answer as accepted since this helped resolve your issue. (Click the checkmark to the left next to this answer.)